# Azure B2C SAML-IDP static SP metadata

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

Is there a way to configure the SP metadata as static information instead of setting the SP metadata endpoint url in Azure B2C.

I will appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems - no. As an alternative way you can host your metadata somewhere and put the link to the metadata file to the Azure B2C Application Registration's settings. For example, you can easily do that by using Azure Blob Storage.